# i am getting different value in different device after running same sql statment

Tags: android-sqlite

I am developing data driven android application and i am  getting  different value in different Devices   after running the same the SQL statement

**SQL:**

```
select  sum(quantity_on_hand-issued_quantity) as Quantity_On_Hand, a.vaccine_name 
from  vaccine a, vaccine_detail b
where a.vaccine_id=b.vaccine_id and strftime("%m", b.date) < '11' and a.vaccine_id= 4
```

To elaborate : When it runs on the Emulator it returns a value, however when I run it on real Android device it returns null.

Comment: It would be nice to know the exact format of b.date. I understand the same thing works in the emulator, however, I have received this issue in the past with regards to input format on Android. Personally I would just recommend using raw SQL statements. At the very least you might gain insight into a format mismatch you may be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase the RAM of emulator and try it .. U should rely more on the value returned by device.